# If it hadn't been for

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

It's correct using would + present indefinite, after

> If it hadn't been for

? For to express the action of what is happening now?
For example:

> If it hadn't been for my parents I wouldn't live now.

instead:

> If it hadn't been for my parents I wouldn't been have born.

Or use continuous form?

> If it hadn't been for my parents I wouldn't living now.

Answer (score 2):

It would be true (and grammatical) for you to say both that:

*If it hadn't been for my parents*

> ....I wouldn't HAVE BEEN born

referring to an action in the past that marked the start of your life

and

> ....I wouldn't BE living now

referring to the continuing consequence of your having been born.

Note the changes to your examples.

Although you might have said:

> I wouldn't live now

The continuous form (*be living now*) is more natural in this context as you are still living.

In general, we use the *present continuous* to talk about what we are doing now/today/soon/in the future, as in:

> I am going to the shops/going swimming/going home/going to France next year

We use the simple present to talk about our habits, routines:

> I go to the shops/swim/practise twice a week.

Comment: What tense would you use with the verb "exist" instead of "live"?

Comment: @V.V. Depends on the context. Robinson Crusoe might well have said: **I am existing in dreadful circumstances**. Rene Descartes might have said: **I exist; therefore I am**.